# "That" instead of "those"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Why has the author used "*that*" in the sentence below? I think "*those*" is correct here. Please help me to understand it if I am wrong.

> . . . takes decisions and takes actions that promote the efficiency and effectiveness of its own department and **that** of other departments.

Comment: Do you mean *makes decisions* rather than *takes decisions*? If *takes decisions* is how it was written, this calls into question the usefulness of discussing *that* vs. *those* — that is, are we even looking at a native English specimen here?

Comment: *"its own department"*? What is it, a dog? a table?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Is there anything wrong with 'taking' decisions? As far as I know both 'take' and 'make' are legitimate collocations here.

Comment: @JulesCocovin: I just did a COCA search. There are only a relative handful of *taking decisions* (some of which are along the lines of *taking decisions out of the hands of . . .*) compared to an abundance of *making decisions.* That said, it appears that *taking decisions* might be British English. At least my AmE ears have never heard it.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I looked it up here: http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=decision and it appears 'take' is an option. Here: https://www.lexico.com/definition/decision there is an example with 'take', too. '‘It seems like she was detached from it all, prepared to let them take the decisions for her.’ Having said that, examples with 'make' are more common, and the make option, too, sounds more natural to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ambiguous if it should be *that* or *those*.

The noun phrase is *efficiency and effectiveness*. But the phrase can can be treated as either a single compound concept (leading to the singular pronoun *that*) or the conjunction of two distinct things (leading to the plural pronoun *those*).

In other words:

> 1)  . . . the <sup>efficiency and effectiveness</sup> of its own department and **that** of other departments.
>
> 2) . . . the <sup>efficiency</sup> and <sup>effectiveness</sup> of its own department and **those** of other departments.

---

This is no different than *drinking and driving* or *fish and chips*.

For example:

> The *thing* I don't like *is* <sup>drinking and driving</sup>.
>   The *things* I don't like *are* <sup>drinking</sup> and <sup>driving.</sup>

Neither interpretation is necessarily right or wrong. It depends entirely on how each person interprets the phrase—as a singular compound or a conjoined plural.

Comment: Can _efficiency and effectiveness_ really work as a compound concept, though? In theory, you’re right, but does it work in practice here? I suppose the two words are close enough to being synonyms that they may be used here as a sort of hendiadys to refer to the concept, but even so, the singular form sounds off to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet *Efficiency and effectiveness is a good technique to be employed by any employee.* It can *sound* wrong to you (or anyone) but the point is the intent of the author. *Should* the singular be used? That's a different question, and one of style, not of grammar. I can come up with a large number of example of compounds that are treated in different ways.

Comment: Just remove "that or those" and it will still make sense. It automatically gets co-related.

Comment: Eventually everything can just be a matter of style and not grammar, depending on how you define "style" and "grammar". However, the point remains that it is not culturally common to use "effectiveness and efficiency" as a singular noun, in a way that it is with "fish and chips" and "drinking and driving". I'm also not sure that I would agree that the point of all textual interpretation is "the point of the author". That might be so with some schools of thought on poetry and literature, but for corporate communications like this typically what is "correct" is what's common in the culture.

Answer (score 1):

> . . . *takes decisions and takes actions that promote the efficiency*
>   *and effectiveness of its own department and that / <s>those</s> of other departments*.

It can only be singular "that".

In their independent use, demonstratives function as 'fused' determiner-head in NP structure. Thus "that" is interpreted as "that efficiency and effectiveness".

"That" is appropriate here because "efficiency" and "effectiveness" are so closely related as to be interpreted as a single concept; "those" is inappropriate because it would leave people puzzling over what precisely was the distinction intended between the two.

Comment: This seems completely wrong to me. We can’t say “*that efficiency and effectiveness of other departments” either, so I don’t see what that test is intended to show. The underlying form is “**the** e. and e. of other d.s”, and while _the_ does not inflect for number, the demonstrative that fills the gap in head function does. Since _efficiency and effectiveness_ is unquestionably plural, it can only be plural _those_ to me; singular _that_ is quite ungrammatical in my English. (Cf. CGEL:412)

Comment: So you would also say, for example, “The population and the birth rate of India far exceed that of the US”? Or “Sylvia’s poetry and her prose are both on par with that of Hemingway”? Those are both utterly ungrammatical to me. There is also the fact that the demonstrative here is _not_ simple a fused determiner-head, but a replacement for an impossible fused determiner-head _*the_. You cannot necessarily expect a replacement form to match the determiner, rather than the underlying head.

Answer (score 1):

*That* is a fused determiner head in the example given. When it comes to coordination of nouns, demonstratives *this* and *that* agree with the head. For example:

*
*Those cup and saucer.*

The heads here are singular *cup* and *saucer* so the demonstrative would have to be singular *this*.

This explains why singular *that* is used and not plural *those*, which is clearly ungrammatical if the heads are added back in:

*
*those efficiency and effectiveness of other departments*

*That* is put to good use here as it takes the place of *the* which is not allowed as a fused determiner head.

*
*...promote the efficiency and effectiveness of its own department and **the** of other departments*

For this to work, as the other answers have mentioned, there must be a close association between the two coordinates allowing us to think of them as a unit. This condition is satisfied by *efficiency* and *effectiveness* as one would seem to promote the other.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the speaker and hearer have a shared singular conception of "efficiency and effectiveness", like as a company policy, then this is going to sound wrong to most readers, or at least those readers that stop and think about it. So it should be "those", because there are two objects being promoted, which are typically deemed to be separate.

Although who knows what the author intended, it seems like they either (a) made an antecedent error; or (b) are trying to make "efficiency and effectiveness" into a unified noun phrase, which really only works if your potential listeners share that concept.

**An antecedent processing error.** This is a common enough error even among native speakers, who often use the heuristic of looking to the last word referred to ("effectiveness") and inserting the corresponding pronoun form.

So as written the sentence "sounds" right on a very quick read (or writing) because one's mind does a kind of lookback function, like "was the last thing I said a plural noun or singular? ok, singular, let's say 'that' instead of 'those'".

In about 99% of sentences that heuristic works. Here it fails, and one has to really read the sentence slowly and be like "ok, these are two things that, grammatically, have to be put together to act as a plural, and so I use the plural pronoun to refer to them". That would be my suspicion as to what happened here.

**Treatment as a singular noun phrase requires shared understanding of its singularity.** There is, as Jason Blassford states, the possibility that the author intended for "efficiency and effectiveness" to be a singular noun phrase, like "fish and chips" or "drinking and driving".  However, the difference is that "efficiency and effectiveness" do not exist most people's lexicon as a unified concept.

So while I, like most readers, would recognize either "pass me that fish and chips" (referring to the whole basket of food a single item) or "pass me those fish and chips" (referring to them is a collection of items) as grammatically valid, that is only because writer and reader share an understanding of them as a pair that can be unified.

"The thing I don't like is drinking and driving" and "The things I don't like are drinking and driving" are two sentences with two different meanings: the writer of the former is probably ok with you day-drinking at home in quarantine; but the writer of the latter probably isn't. The salient thing here is that the former only sounds grammatical because there is a widespread understanding of "drinking and driving" as a unified concept.

If one were to say, for example, "The thing I don't like is efficiency and effectiveness," in most contexts the listener is going to be like "Uh, wait, what? Which thing don't you like? Efficiency? Or effectiveness?" That sort of phrase would only work if the speaker and listener shared a unified concept of "efficiency and effectiveness", like if that were the name of a policy at a company where they both work.